# Suppose $f[g(x)] = \sqrt{(3x+4)}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1-x}{2+x}$. Evaluate $g(0)$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This was a problem in our recent test on Functions and I could not find a way to do it.

I assume that first, we'd have to find the $g(x)$ that was used as the domain of $f(x)$ to get the given $f(g(x))$.

I've seen tutorials online about getting the two functions that form a Composite of a Function, but I don't see how that could be applied with this question.

Does anyone know what type of problem it is?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac {1-x}{2+x}$.

So $f(g(x)) = \frac {1-g(x)}{2+g(x)}$ but we also are told

$f(g(x)) = \sqrt{3x+4}$ so $\frac {1-g(x)}{2+g(x)} = \sqrt{3x+4}$.  In theory we can solve for $g(x)$ in terms of $x$ and that will tell us what $g(x)$.

But it's unclear if that is what we are supposed to do.  Are we supposed to find $g(x)$ for all $x$ or just $g(0)$ for $x =0$.

The later is easy.  $f(g(0)) = \frac {1-g(0)}{2+g(0)} = \sqrt {3*0 + 4} = \sqrt{4} = 2$.

So $\frac {1-g(0)}{2+g(0)} = 2$

$1-g(0) = 2(2+g(0))$

$1- g(0) = 4 + 2g(0)$

$-3 = 3g(0)$ so $g(0) =-1$.

To solve for $g(x)$ for all $x$ we do

$\frac {1-g(x)}{2+g(x)} = \sqrt{3x+4}$

$1-g(x) = (2+g(x))\sqrt {3x+4}$

$1-g(x) = \sqrt{3x+4}g(x) + 2\sqrt{3x+4}$

$\sqrt{3x+4}g(x) + g(x) = 1-2\sqrt{3x+4}$

$g(x)(\sqrt {3x+4}+1) = 1-2\sqrt {3x+4}$

$g(x) = \frac {1-2\sqrt{3x+4}}{\sqrt{3x+4} + 1}$

....

So $g(0) = \frac {1-2\sqrt{3*0+4}}{\sqrt{3*0+4} + 1}=\frac {1-2*2}{2+1}=\frac{-3}3=-1$.

Comment: Thank you for putting it in detail, I think I get the idea now.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $f(g(0))=2$. Now find $x$ such that $f(x)=2$. For that
$$\frac{1-x}{2+x}=2 \implies x=-1.$$
Note that $f$ is a one-one function (you can verify it using the definition). Thus $g(0)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation : $f(g(x))=\sqrt{3x+4}$, notice when you plug in $x=0$, you get $f(g(0))=2.$

Put $g(0)$ in the expression for $f(x)$, as we know its value at that point.

$$f(g(0))=\frac{1-g(0)}{2+g(0)} = 2$$

$$3g(0)=-3$$

$$g(0)=-1$$